# How does this Dynamic Time Warping code work?

Tags: java, algorithm, dtw

I'm studying this code to find the Dynamic Time Warping distance, but I can't understand some parts.

```
public static void d(int[] x1, int[] x2) {
    int n1 = x1.length;
    int n2 = x2.length;
    double[][] table = new double[2][n2 + 1];
    table[0][0] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++) {
        table[0][i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {
        table[1][0] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n2; j++) {
            double cost = Math.abs(x1[i-1] - x2[j-1]);
            double min = table[0][j - 1];
            if (min > table[0][j]) {
                min = table[0][j];
            }
            if (min > table[1][j - 1]) {
                min = table[1][j - 1];
            }
            table[1][j] = cost + min;
        }
        double[] swap = table[0];
        table[0] = table[1];
        table[1] = swap;
    }
    System.out.println(table[0][n2]);
}
```

First, why does this line create a "vertical" array `[2][n2+1]`?

```
double[][] table = new double[2][n2 + 1];
```

Second, in the last line why do we print `table[0][n2]`? Shouldn't the final value be `[n1][n2]`?

Finally, why do we swap here?

```
double[] swap = table[0];
table[0] = table[1];
table[1] = swap;
```

Comment: we use this main code.
  int[] x1 = { 1,1,2,3,3,2};
  int[] x2 = { 1,2,3,3,2,1 };
  
  d(x1,x2);

Comment: You will want to post all key information in with your question, not in comments.

Comment: Additionally, some context as to where this code is from, and what it's supposed to be doing.  'Dynamic time warping' could be interpreted in a LOT of ways.

Comment: Did you read [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)?  And there are many articles referenced in this article which might assist your understanding of the topic and the attendant code.